# Avro schema (or Json) for SObject, Platform Events and SOQL queries

Tags: schema

I would like to generate Schema for SObjects, Platform Events and SOQL so to be used in a typed programming language.

I see it is possible to obtain the Avro schema for Platform Events here:
 https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_eventschema.htm but I am not sure about:

- Is the standard (non compact schema) a Json schema? Where is this documented?
- Can you get similar schema for SObject (The SObject Describe contains a schema, but is the schema a valid json schema?)
- What about SOQL queries?